# Google ML kit Barcode Scanner example app for android not able to detect barcodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to use the Google ML kit barcode detection feature. For this, I have installed [this example app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) provided by google. I have also connected my app to one of my firebase projects. When I open the app and go to LivePreviewActivity in that Barcode detection. The camera starts but no barcode is detected!. 
As per the quick start guide I've also added

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="barcode" />
```

in my manifest file. 
Also I have included this

```
FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options =
            new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(
                            FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_CODE_128)
                    .build();
```

in BarcodeScanningProcessor.java file.

The errors I'm getting is:

> Barcode detection failed
>   com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the
>   barcode detection model to be downloaded. Please wait.
>
> E/BarcodeNativeHandle: Error Loading module
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.chimera.DynamiteModuleInitializer"

I've installed this app on two phones Huawei Mate 8 and Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. The app is not able to detect barcodes from both the phones.

My aim is to detect/scan barcodes from live camera preview. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the first part of the question *"Waiting for the barcode detection model to be downloaded. Please wait."*:

This can happen if there is not enough storage on the device or the data connection is not there on the device. Clear out the data of the Google Play Services and retrying should work:

*`Settings->Apps->Google Play Services->Storage->Manage Space->Clear All Data`*

On the *meta-data tag in the manifest* part of the question:

That helps with the production use case i.e. when the end-user installs the app from the Play Store, the models are downloaded at install time with that meta-data tag. However, during the development you still have to wait for the model to be downloaded once.

On the last part of the question about Dynamite module loading error (I don't have enough reputation to add a comment yet, so adding it here):

What Android version and the Google Play services version are you running?

Comment: You can run below command to query Google Play services version. Let us know the result: adb shell dumpsys activity service com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.GmsCoreStatsService | grep 'com\.google\.android\.gms \['

Comment: Note that in above command, there's another \ before [, somehow StackOverflow threw away that \

Comment: Thanks it works clearing all data (only cache is not sufficient)

Comment: is there a way to check if the model has been downloaded or not?

Answer (score 3):

Add this dependency. It worked for me.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.2'
```

Comment: This is also mentioned on the documentation when using version 24.0.0 and newer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes